# should I sign the user with his Id or hi login?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

the ids are autoincrement 1,2,3 ... etc.
and the login's are string

when I do `FormsAuth.SignIn(` **//here should I use the login or the ids**

the logins aren't seen by anybody,
but the ids aren't hard to guess (for some random person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you do your authentication. The standard generated forms-authentication expects a Username for the user to log in.

So when the user tries to login you should check his username and password against the database. If everything is correct then you can do.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("UserName",true/false);
```

If you wrote your custom membership validation then you can set the AuthCookie to something else like the Id or Email. It just has to be unique.

What you are saying about the Id's aren't hard to quess shouldn't mather. Unauthorized persons shouldn't be able to do the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. You always have to check if the pass and username is correct so.

Hope it's clear enough for you?

Comment: I was just thinking that they could login, get the cookie, decrypt it see that it is e.g. 57 and edit it to 59 encrypt it back and put it in the cookie

Comment: There is some sort of safe check on the cookies asp.net makes. The moment you change something the cookie is invalid and you will be logged out. Cookie stealing is still possible thou